# AS3 Positioning Mess Up in Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm creating array to add multiple child on the stage when click. When the child are close to each other, I add a Line to bond both of them together.

The problem is, the position of X and Y got mess up in my array, where the line did not move to the correct coordination of my child.

**Edit:**
The original problem has been fixed; but need to restrict when a point can be added to one of the arrays (cArray, hArray, xArray, oArray), based on chemistry rules:

[image: Example of running code]

Updated code:

```
package  
{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class main extends MovieClip 
    {
        public static var cArray:Array = new Array();
        public static var hArray:Array = new Array();
        public static var xArray:Array = new Array();
        public static var oArray:Array = new Array();

        var bondArray:Shape=new Shape();

        public function main() 
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopAllDrag);

            add_c_mol.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickCmol);
            add_h_mol.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickHmol);
            add_x_mol.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickXmol);
            add_o_mol.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickOmol);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkBond);
        }

        private function stopAllDrag(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stopDrag();
        }

        private function clickCmol(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            cArray.push(new C_mol());
            cArray[cArray.length - 1].x=112;
            cArray[cArray.length - 1].y=197;
            addChild(cArray[cArray.length - 1]);
            cArray[cArray.length - 1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragCmol);
            cArray[cArray.length - 1].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,trashC);
        }
        private function dragCmol(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.target.startDrag();
        }
        private function trashC (e:Event):void
        {
            if(e.target.hitTestObject(trash))
            {
                e.target.visible=false;
            }
            if(e.target.y<180)
            {
                e.target.y=180;
                stopDrag();
            }
        }



        private function clickHmol(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            hArray.push(new H_mol());
            hArray[hArray.length - 1].x=280;
            hArray[hArray.length - 1].y=174;
            addChild(hArray[hArray.length - 1]);
            hArray[hArray.length - 1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragHmol);
            hArray[hArray.length - 1].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,trashH);
        }
        private function dragHmol(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.target.startDrag();
        }
        private function trashH (e:Event):void
        {
            if(e.target.hitTestObject(trash))
            {
                e.target.visible=false;
            }
            if(e.target.y<152)
            {
                e.target.y=152;
                stopDrag();
            }
        }



        private function clickXmol(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            xArray.push(new X_mol());
            xArray[xArray.length - 1].x=474;
            xArray[xArray.length - 1].y=201;
            addChild(xArray[xArray.length - 1]);
            xArray[xArray.length - 1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragXmol);
            xArray[xArray.length - 1].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,trashX);
        }
        private function dragXmol(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.target.startDrag();
        }
        private function trashX (e:Event):void
        {
            if(e.target.hitTestObject(trash))
            {
                e.target.visible=false;
            }
            if(e.target.y<186)
            {
                e.target.y=186;
                stopDrag();
            }
        }


        private function clickOmol(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            oArray.push(new O_mol());
            oArray[oArray.length - 1].x=648;
            oArray[oArray.length - 1].y=189;
            addChild(oArray[oArray.length - 1]);
            oArray[oArray.length - 1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragOmol);
            oArray[oArray.length - 1].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,trashO);
        }
        private function dragOmol(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.target.startDrag();
        }
        private function trashO (e:Event):void
        {
            if(e.target.hitTestObject(trash))
            {
                e.target.visible=false;
            }
            if(e.target.y<187)
            {
                e.target.y=187;
                stopDrag();
            }
        }

        private function checkBond(e:Event):void
        {
            bondArray.graphics.clear();
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < main.cArray.length; i++) 
            {
                for (var j:uint = 0; j < main.hArray.length; j++) 
                {
                    if (Math.pow(Math.abs(main.cArray[i].x - main.hArray[j].x),2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(main.cArray[i].y - main.hArray[j].y),2) < Math.pow(100,2))
                    {
                        //trace("yes");
                        bondArray.graphics.lineStyle(8,00000, 1);
                        bondArray.graphics.moveTo(main.cArray[i].x,main.cArray[i].y);
                        bondArray.graphics.lineTo(main.hArray[j].x,main.hArray[j].y);
                        addChildAt(bondArray,0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //bondArray.graphics.clear();

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the code correctly, you have two different types of children:

Children of cArray and children of hArray. Am I correct in expecting the lines to have one end as a cArray element, and the other end as a hArray element? (This is what your code is currently doing)

Another issue is how your nested loop is operating. If you're looking for a line from `cArray[0]` to `hArray[0]`, and `cArray[1]` to `hArray[1]`; but not `cArray[0]` to `cArray[1]`, etc. then you need to have a constant index without a nested for loop:

```
var numLines = ???;
for (var i:uint = 0; i < numLines; i++) 
{
   var cPosition = cArray[index];
   var hPosition = hArray[index];

   //Then draw the line between them.
}
```

As a note, your vector distance math looks okay, but there looks to be another issue with your graphics drawing.

It looks like at some point you were creating a new shape for each line, which you are correct in thinking, is unnecessary. However, you're clearing the previous lines every time you create a new one.

You want to clear the graphics before you start any of the drawing for this frame (Ie. above the for loops):

```
bondArray.graphics.clear();
for (var i:uint = 0; i < main.cArray.length; i++)   
{
...
```

**Edit:**

To your second question - "*What I wanted to do is only 1 C able to connect to the H, which means H can only accept 1 bond.*"

Where you're adding lines between the (molecules?), you just need to count how many you've already connected. So where you're currently doing this:

```
//1. Add this counter.
var numberCToHConnections:int = 0;
for (var i:uint = 0; i < main.cArray.length; i++) 
{
    for (var j:uint = 0; j < main.hArray.length; j++) 
    {
        // 3. Check if the counter is less than 1, 
        // if it is, then we dont want any more lines to be drawn.
        if( numberCToHConnections < 1 ) {
            if (Math.pow(Math.abs(main.cArray[i].x - main.hArray[j].x),2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(main.cArray[i].y - main.hArray[j].y),2) < Math.pow(100,2))
            {
                //2. Then increment the counter each time you draw the line.
                numberCToHConnections = numberCToHConnections + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks..

1 more question, what if I only want to have only 1 line connected to hArray. how should I make use of the boolean?

Comment: @user3251836, I don't quite understand. Could you draw a simple image on paint to display what you're trying to do? (make sure to label which dots/lines would be associated with what variables in the code)

Comment: as u can see from the image. the C,H,X,O above is the button. when they are clicked, child added on the stage below. and from the image, as u can see, there are currently 3 C connected to 1 H.  
what i wanted to do is only 1 C able to connect to the H, which means H can only accept 1 bond.  edited code uploaded as well

Comment: Ah. This helps a lot. You should delete your updated code below, I've edited your original post and put it and the photo in there.

Comment: Thanks. I had edited the code, but the problem is, when i added another H on stage, it can not connect to other C anymore. View image for better understanding: http://oi60.tinypic.com/34fchfc.jpg

Comment: Is there anyway to have boolean/counter for each individual molecules so that I can check the connection? Thanks :)